# How can i show image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I build a folder assets and added there my logo.png. But it shows unable to load asset: assets/logo.png . How can I fix this? Below you can find my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:color/color.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
         color: Colors.grey[900],
         child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 150,
              child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
            )
          ],
         ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you put the assets folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add also pubspec.yaml file like this.

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/logo.png
```

Comment: Emre . I did it but still same problem

Comment: Sometimes you may need to delete and reinstall the application.

or if you are using android studio you need to do invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Usually we use like this. We create images folder under assets folder. After we define like this. 
    - assets/images/ 
After that i add all photos into images folder.

Comment: I did what you say but same problem. I built the folder images inside assets

Comment: Can you send a picture your pubspec.yaml file and assets folder please

Comment: How can I add here? @Yunus

Comment: @Amarildo Edit your question.

Comment: i did it now @Yunus

Comment: Can u place ur image outside the row and inside a container . To see if it is rendering or not

Comment: @Amarildo Can you tick the answer as the correct answer? Thank you

Comment: problem solved. @Yunus . I needed to close the ide and open again

Answer (score 0):

first you need create a asset folder in your project root folder, like this:

[image]

then in your `pubspec.yaml` , under `flutter:` define it like this:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

[image]

then run `flutter pub get` now if you call image, you can see it:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/test.jpeg'),
```

[image]

**Note:** if you still not getting image, please stop project and close ide, then open it again run flutter pub get then run then project.

Comment: I did it exactly as you but still same error. @eamirho3ein

Comment: please stop project and close ide, then open it again run flutter pub get then run then project.

Comment: ok @eamirho3ein

Comment: Glad to hear that, please if it was helpful to you, up vote and approve it so other people could find it easier.